# Testing If an object is nil or not

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"play"]){

    NSLog(@"play was touched");

    SKScene *mainGameScene = [[MainGame alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
    if (!mainGameScene){
    SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition fadeWithColor:[UIColor blackColor] duration:0.5];
    [self.view presentScene:mainGameScene transition:transition];
    }

}
```

}

From my understanding the code above checks if `mainGameScene` is nil and if it is it then goes through the if statement.

Is this beneficial at all or is it just a waste of code because if the method that this code is in is called multiple times won't it create new objects of `SKScene`?

Comment: if you alloc/init `mainGameScene` just before `if(!mainGameScene)` then... it seems the if block will never be true and hence won't execute in the first place.

Comment: how do i test an object before its been alloc/init?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is used to check if `mainGameScene` is initialized, because you can't `presentScene` if it is `nil`.
if you want only to check if object is initialized, then

```
SKScene *mainGameScene;
//creates new variable - place it at the beginning of the code, before @implementation and @interface
if(mainGameScene){
// it is already inited (you have already tapped once), it will be called always, since it is inited at else
//it is called when you tap the second, the third time, etcetera
SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition fadeWithColor:[UIColor blackColor] duration:0.5];
[self.view presentScene:mainGameScene transition:transition];
}else
{
//Calls only once, when you first touching the screen, and initing mainGameScene.
//It won't be called ANYMORE, since it is inited.
mainGameScene = [[MainGame alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
}
```

The code you have now is useless, as it is trying to do something with object, that isn't initialized.
In my case, your `mainGameScene` won't be reinitialized, once it is inited.

Comment: so if this is called multiple times it won't alloc a new `mainGameScene` every time? @AlieN

Comment: Your init method is called until your scene is initialized. It won't be called again if it is already initialized, so it won't create a new mainGameScene every time.

Comment: i've updated the code maybe you will understand what i mean now?

Comment: In touchesBegan?? Then, no, it will be reinitialized. You should place your init code in the method that calls once, when loaded

Comment: so the code above is practically useless the way i am using it, any idea on how i can check if its been initialised with it still being able to change scenes when a touch is recognised?

Comment: Shouldn't it init the object because of the else statement? then after the second click present the scene?

Comment: `SKScene *mainGameScene;
        if (!mainGameScene){
        mainGameScene = [[MainGame alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
        SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition fadeWithColor:[UIColor blackColor] duration:0.5];
        [self.view presentScene:mainGameScene transition:transition];
        }` and this will I'm assuming